# Locate and updatedb doesn't work. What should I do?

Tags: linux, debian

My `locate` command doesn't work, but I found out I had to run `updatedb`. However, upon invoking that command, bash says `bash: updatedb: command not found`. What should I do?

Comment: Either updatedb is not installed, either it's not in your $PATH variable. When running updatedb, you must do it as root or with sudo.

Comment: You could look for updatedb with "find" find / -name updatedb -print

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you need to install the locate program. In a debian lenny system, the /usr/bin/updatedb file is a symlink to /etc/alternatives/updatedb which is a symlink to /usr/bin/updatedb.findutils.

Using dpkg -S you can find what package a file belongs to:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/updatedb.findutils 
locate: /usr/bin/updatedb.findutils
```

So I think you need to install locate and then run updatedb as root.

Edit: yes, you need the locate package. In the file /usr/share/doc/findutils/NEWS.Debian.gz you can read:

> locate is no longer included in the
>   findutils package. It has been split
>   off to a separate package "locate".

and then in /usr/share/doc/findutils/changelog.Debian.gz, on the changelog on 11 nov 2007:

> Split off locate/updatedb to a
>   separate package.

Answer (score 16):

It was not installed and not in the directories listed by natxo, but I found a solution to install it. Thank you for the lead guys!

http://www.nicecabbage.com/2009/08/install-locate-and-updatedb-on-centos-and-debian/

In root: `apt-get install locate`

Comment: ?? apparently I have not explained it properly. In a debian system *with* updatedb installed, using dpkg -S has told me what package it belonged to. That is why I wrote you needed the locate package, which is what you have done. Glad you found it on your own, though.

Comment: For CentOS/RHEL, it's yum -y install mlocate.

Answer (score 5):

In order for your locate command to work properly, install locate from apt and then run the command updatedb.

```
sudo apt install locate
sudo updatedb
```

Comment: on newer ubuntu versions install is not enough, there is no executable updatedb, but there is updatedb.findutils and updatedb.findutils

Answer (score 2):

Must of the command that must be run as root are not in the user's $PATH so just run:

> $ sudo updatedb

and  it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to invoke 'updatedb' with administrative privileges. 
As far is I remeber, findutils are part of a standard Debian distribution /installation, so have a look at /etc/updatedb.conf and /etc/cron.daily/(s)locate.

If nothing's broken, the built of a fresh updatedb [locate database] is a daily cronjob, so you dont'have to worry about this anyway